# Add r.null functionality to GRASS toolbox algorithms in QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, nodata

I'd like to be able to use GRASS's r.null operation in the QGIS processing toolbox (not via the GRASS plugin). However, it doesn't seem to be available. How would I go about adding code to allow for the r.null algorithm?

Comment: Try QGIS 2.16, I have found r.null in the processing toolbox (but not in QGIS 2.14).

Comment: r.null command is available in QGIS 2.16 or higher. https://hub.qgis.org/issues/6893

Comment: Only issue is that 2.16 is a bit unstable. Last time I updated to 2.16, from ubuntugis-unstable, it broke all of the GIS software on my machine... it should be easy enough to add r.null to the LTR version (2.14) as well, right?